# NodeJS - MySQL query error

Tags: mysql, node.js

My query works fine if the person exist in my table, but if he/she does not; the NodeJS will give me an error.

```
function ClientConnected(remoteClient)
{
    debugLog(remoteClient.name + " connected to the server. (ID: " + remoteClient.networkId + ") Loading player data..");
    sql.query('SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `character_name` = ?', [remoteClient.name], function(err, rows)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            debugLog('[DB] Error when loading ' + remoteClient.name + "'s (" + remoteClient.networkId + ') data: ' + err.code);
        } else {
            players[remoteClient.networkId] = {
                'a_socialid' : rows[0].account_socialid,
                'i_money' : rows[0].inventory_money,
            };
            debugLog("Successfully loaded " + remoteClient.name + "'s (" + remoteClient.networkId + ") data..");
        }
    });

}
events.Add("ClientConnected", ClientConnected);
```

If someone joins with the name that already exists in the table, it will load the players data:

[image]

But if not, it gives me an error. (TypeError, undefined, blabla)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that a record was returned. Maybe something like this:

```
if(err)
{
    debugLog('[DB] Error when loading ' + remoteClient.name + "'s (" + remoteClient.networkId + ') data: ' + err.code);
} else if (rows.length === 0) {
    debugLog('Nothing returned from database');
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Presumably the `err` result would only give you feedback on the actual query, not the data it returns.